# Angular JS 1 - How to deploy independent angular JS app in Heroku without any server files

Tags: angularjs, heroku, web-hosting

My angular web app just interacts with WebAPI and changes the view in angular way.

For testing locally, I used

```
http-server . -o
```

Should I use NodeJS or any other server just to serve the contents using Heroku?

Can anyone help me to host my angular app in Heroku (if possible, through Dropbox options.)?